# Changing schema incrementally with "monolithic" migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in in a development environment, and though I understand migrations, I'm beginning to want (just because it seems more fun) to define my changes in a monolithic schema file that shows what I want the whole schema to be (not `schema.rb`, but maybe a migration file) instead of creating small, incremental changes through migrations. The only thing I can think of would be write migrations as normal, but have every migration dump all tables and re-create them the way I want them. Is this madness?

I've had a look at the rails guide Active Record Migrations and I've done some searching around. It seems like I'm going against the grain and should just define incremental migrations. I should not be messing with `schema.rb` and then using `rake db:schema:load` because that's intended for deployment only, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is madness. Don't go against the grain >:D

Seriously though, why would you want that when you could use `git` to see a snapshot of your `schema.rb` at any given time?

As an aside, what we typically do (we as in every company I've worked for so far) is delete all of our old migrations after a certain point. Ex, in March of this year, I wiped out all migrations older than January 2015.

Comment: This. Rails convention always, always, always. Don't go against the grain. I've been fighting against Rails convention and life becomes very hard for you if you attempt to do that, especially in regards to database stuff.